# Is it a bad idea to count specific letters in string using regex?

Tags: javascript, regex, match, regex-negation

I'm looking for letters (a to m) in the string using regex. I already found a way to do the same thing without regex, but is it possible to do this with regex and is it a good or bad idea to use regex when counting specific letters in the string?

**When using regex findError.length value is wrong for me, the other way is working fine**

This is how I search for letters using regex

```
function printerError(s) {
            let findError = s.match(/[a-mA-M]+/g).toString();
            let sum = (s.length - findError.length);
            return sum + '/' + s.length;
        }

    console.log(printerError("anananaanaann"));
```

**
**Working code**

```
    function printerError2(s) {
      const goodLetters = Array.from("abcdefghijklm");
      let total = s.length;
      let badLetters = 0;
      for (let i = 0; i < total; i++) {
        if ( !goodLetters.includes(s.charAt(i)) ) {
          badLetters++;
        }
      }
      return `${badLetters}/${total}`;
    }

console.log(printerError2("anananaanaann"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This returns you the number of chars between a-mA-M in your string:

```js
function printerError(s) {
  return s.length - s.replace(/[a-mA-M]/g, '').length;
}

console.log(printerError("anananaanaann"));
```

Or you can even do:

```js
function printerError(s) {
  return (s.match(/[a-mA-M]/g) || []).length;
}

console.log(printerError("anananaanaann"));
```